# Same json field set to different attribute in java pojo

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I want to set one json field to two attribute in a java pojo. When i use jsonproperty for dublicate attribute in pojo, one field be a null everytime.

My pojo object is;

```
public class PojoTest {

    private String receiverAccountNo;

    private String originalReceiverAccountNo;

    @JsonProperty("receiverAccountNo")
    public String getOriginalReceiverAccountNo() {
        return originalReceiverAccountNo;
    }

    @JsonProperty("receiverAccountNo")
    public void setOriginalReceiverAccountNo(String originalReceiverAccountNo) {
        this.originalReceiverAccountNo = originalReceiverAccountNo;
    }

    public String getReceiverAccountNo() {
        return receiverAccountNo;
    }

    public void setReceiverAccountNo(String receiverAccountNo) {
        this.receiverAccountNo = receiverAccountNo;
    }
}
```

My request is;

```
{
    "receiverAccountNo":"566665"
}
```

My test controller is;

```
@PostMapping("/test2")
public String test2(@RequestBody PojoTest pojoTest) {
    return "OriginalReceiverAccountNo:"+pojoTest.getOriginalReceiverAccountNo()+" ReceiverAccountNo:"+pojoTest.getReceiverAccountNo();
}
```

When i run code i am getting following response;

OriginalReceiverAccountNo:566665 ReceiverAccountNo:null

I am using jackson-annotation-2.9.0 dependency.How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Try annotating JsonProperty for the getting and setter to ReceiverAccountNo. I believe it is null because you haven't told the annotation to fill in that property for you.

Comment: I getted an exception ;  11-Feb-2019 23:44:32.858 WARNING [http-nio-8081-exec-1] org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.logWarningIfNecessary Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.ykb.frd.fraudws.PojoTest]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "receiverAccountNo": com.ykb.frd.fraudws.PojoTest#setReceiverAccountNo(1 params) vs com.ykb.frd.fraudws.PojoTest#setOriginalReceiverAccountNo(1 params)

Comment: See my answer below. I don't think you need the annotations over the setter functions.

Comment: I tried your solution but received same exception

Answer (score 3):

You can use constructor mapping like this, that sets two properties given one `@JsonProperty`

```
public class Pojo
{
    private final String receiverAccountNo;
    private final String originalReceiverAccountNo;


    @JsonCreator
    public Observation(
            @JsonProperty("receiverAccountNo") String value)
    {
        this.receiverAccountNo = value;
        this.originalReceiverAccountNo = value;
    }
```

I prefer this method to create immutable objects, but you can keep it mutable if you like

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. One json field is mapped to exactly one pojo property.

You can however change the behavior of your pojo so that the setter of either one sets the value of the other as well:

```
@JsonProperty("receiverAccountNo")
public void setOriginalReceiverAccountNo(String originalReceiverAccountNo) {
    this.originalReceiverAccountNo = originalReceiverAccountNo;
    this.receiverAccountNo = originalReceiverAccountNo;
}


public void setReceiverAccountNo(String receiverAccountNo) {
    this.receiverAccountNo = receiverAccountNo;
    this.originalReceiverAccountNo = receiverAccountNo;
}
```

This way both fields in the pojo will have the same value.

Comment: Thanks for response but i dont want this situation cause when i use your solution if i change recevierAccountNo field, originalRecevierAccountNo updated as recevierAccountNo.